# How to call OpenCV's MatchTemplate method from C#

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I'm trying to get the template's position on the image using [OpenCVSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp) library from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCvSharp-AnyCPU/). Here is the code I've wrote:

```
var image = Cv.LoadImage("Image.png");
var template = Cv.LoadImage("Template.png");
var w = (image.Width - template.Width) + 1;
var h = (image.Height - template.Height) + 1;
IplImage result = new IplImage(w, h, BitDepth.F32, 1);

Console.WriteLine("Image: {0} {1}", image.GetSize(), image.ElemType);
Console.WriteLine("Template: {0} {1}", template.GetSize(), template.ElemType);
Console.WriteLine("Result: {0} {1}", result.GetSize(), result.ElemType);

image.MatchTemplate(image, result, MatchTemplateMethod.CCoeffNormed); // throws exception

double minVal, maxVal;
CvPoint minLoc, maxLoc;
result.MinMaxLoc(out minVal, out maxVal, out minLoc, out maxLoc);
Console.WriteLine(maxLoc);
```

Output:

```
Image: CvSize (Width:2048 Height:1536) U8C3
Template: CvSize (Width:169 Height:128) U8C3
Result: CvSize (Width:1880 Height:1409) F32C1
```

Exception:

> OpenCvSharp.OpenCVException : result.size() == cv::Size(std::abs(img.cols - templ.cols) + 1, std::abs(img.rows - templ.rows) + 1) && result.type() == CV_32F

What's wrong? Where is the error? The size, bit depth and channel number of the result array look correct, but the method still rises the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exception line there should be

`*image.MatchTemplate(*template*, result, MatchTemplateMethod.CCoeffNormed);*`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's wrong with the original C-like code, but I'm managed to get it working with C++ like code:

```
 using OpenCvSharp;
 using OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus;
 // ...

 var image = new Mat("Image.png");
 var template = new Mat("Template.png");

 double minVal, maxVal;
 Point minLoc, maxLoc;
 var result = image.MatchTemplate(template, MatchTemplateMethod.CCoeffNormed);
 result.MinMaxLoc(out minVal, out maxVal, out minLoc, out maxLoc);
 Console.WriteLine("maxLoc: {0}, maxVal: {1}", maxLoc, maxVal);
```